# [ejabberd w/ smack]: how to successfully create a leaf node inside a pubsub collection node

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

A registered user created a collection node on my ejabberd server using smack library and following config:

```
PubSubManager psMgr = new PubSubManager(conn, "pubsub.mydomain");
ConfigureForm CForm = new ConfigureForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
CForm.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);    //anyone can access
CForm.setDeliverPayloads(true);            //allow payloads with notif
CForm.setNotifyDelete(true);               //notify subscribers when nodeis deleted
CForm.setPersistentItems(true);            //save published items in storage @ server
CForm.setPresenceBasedDelivery(false);     //notify subscribers even when offline
CForm.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);  //only publishers can post to this node
CForm.setNodeType(NodeType.collection);
CForm.setChildrenAssociationPolicy(ChildrenAssociationPolicy.all);
CForm.setChildrenMax(65536);
psMgr.createNode("/collection_node", lCForm);
```

....this collection node is created fine. Note that the children association policy is 'all'.

Now, if a different user, registered on the same server, tries to create a leaf node inside this collection node, the server returns 'forbidden - auth' error.

```
ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
form.setNodeType(NodeType.leaf);
form.setCollection("/collection_node");
psMgr.createNode("/collection_node/leaf_node", form);
```

I have these plugins enabled in my ejabberd server for the pubsub module `["collections", "dag", "flat", "hometree", "pep"].`

Can anyone please suggest why should the leaf node creation fail even after the collection node has granted 'all' to associate child nodes with itself.

Smack version is: 4.1.2

ejabberd version: (for some weird reason shows): 0.0 . [However, the server was installed from source code available on (https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/archive/master.zip) in Nov-2015 with erlang installed at the same time (OTP 17.1). So should be pretty much latest unless i screwed up something during installation.]